# Mixing solidguage and column in a graph with highcharter

Tags: highcharts

I have this two dataframes

1) t1 (Var1(numeric), Var2(string), Freq (numeric))

2) pref.media (pref.media (numeric)

I have this separated graphs, but I want to print like two series in the same graph

1) Column chart, ok

```
column1 <- highchart() %>%
 hc_add_series(t1$Freq, type = "column") %>%
 hc_xAxis(categories = t1$Var1) %>%
 hc_plotOptions(series = list(showInLegend = FALSE,dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, color = t1$Var1)))
```

2) Solid gauge chart (ok)

```
gauge1 <- highchart(width = 800, height = 600) %>%
 hc_chart(type = "solidgauge",backgroundColor = "#F0F0F0",marginTop = 50) %>%
 hc_title(text = "Preferencia",style = list(fontSize = "24px")) %>%
 hc_tooltip(borderWidth = 0, backgroundColor = 'none',shadow = FALSE,style = list(fontSize = '16px')) %>%
 hc_pane(startAngle = -90,endAngle = 90) %>%
 hc_yAxis(min = 0,max = 11,lineWidth = 0,tickPositions = list(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)) %>%
 hc_plotOptions(solidgauge = list(borderWidth = '34px',dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, style = list(borderWidth = 3,backgroundColor = 'none',shadow = FALSE, fontSize = '16px',color="#888800")),linecap = 'round',stickyTracking = FALSE)) %>%
 hc_add_series(name = "Preferencia",borderColor = "#000000",data = list(list(color = "#888800"),radius = "100%",innerRadius = "100%",y =  round(pref.media[[1,1]],2)))
```

3) Mixing the charts (not ok, with errors)

```
highchart() %>%
 hc_add_series(t1, "column", hcaes(x = Var1, y = Freq), name = "Preferencia") %>%
 hc_add_series(pref.media, "solidgauge", hcaes(name = "Gauge", y = round(pref.media[[1,1]],2)), name = "Indicador") %>%
 hc_plotOptions(
      series = list(showInLegend = FALSE,pointFormat = "{point.y}%"),
      column = list(colorByPoint = TRUE),
      solidgauge = list(borderWidth = '34px',dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE),linecap = 'round',stickyTracking = FALSE)) %>% 
 hc_pane(startAngle = -90,endAngle = 90) %>%
 hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Porcentaje de preferencia"),labels = list(format = "{value}%"), max = 100) %>% 
 hc_xAxis(categories = t1$Var1) %>%
 hc_title(text = "Título") %>%
 hc_subtitle(text = "Subtítulo")
```

I don't understand the sequence for mixing two series. I tried it with a J.Kunst's example in http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highcharts.html

Thanks

Comment: It is not recommended to combine those two series on one plot, because it won't give you expected effect. In your case, I recommend you to implement two separate charts.

Comment: A lot of thanks Daniel for the answer. I understand you, but in this example two series are the same data: by intervals (columns) and the mean represented with a solidgauge.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether your data is the same for both series, but the series types are too different. Solidgauge works on `pane`, so the easiest way would be to make separate chart for every series.